# `select()` and base R summary function together

Tags: r, dplyr

What is wrong with the following expression:

`weather %>% select(temp) %>% mean(na.rm = TRUE)`

This gives me an error. I thought it flows as select `temp` and then pass it to `mean` function. Why doesn't it work like this?

---

I think a workaround for this is because mean function doesn't accept a dataframe

```
weather %>% select(temp) %$% mean(temp, na.rm=TRUE)
```

Comment: It is necessary to pass the column as an argument inside a `dplyr` function, for this case `mutate()` can accomplish the task:  `weather %>% dplyr::select(temp) %>% dplyr::mutate(temp = mean(temp, na.rm=TRUE))`

Answer (score 2):

You can try using `pull` to extract one column from your dataframe and return a vector. `select` will return a dataframe with one column `temp`.

```
weather %>% pull(temp) %>% mean(na.rm = TRUE)
```

---

Alternatively

```
weather$temp %>% mean(na.rm = TRUE)
```

Or

```
weather[,'temp'] %>% mean(na.rm = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `weather` is a `data.frame` object, it is necessary to pass the column as an argument insde a `dplyr` library function, for this case `mutate()` can accomplish this task:

```
library(dplyr)

weather <- data.frame(weather)

weather <- weather %>% 
             dplyr::select(temp) %>% 
             dplyr::mutate(temp = mean(temp, na.rm=TRUE))
```